# Getting the Caller of the intercepted method in Spring AOP

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Is there a way to get the caller of the intercepted method in Spring AOP (with MVC to be more specific)?
I have two methods say "callerM1()" and "callerM2()" that call an intercepted method "method()". Then I have an aspect like this:

```
@Before("execution(* *.method(..)) && args(arg1)")
public Object doSomething(...){
    //find out which one and do something
}
```

How can I learn which of "callerM1()" or "callerM2()" has called "method()" by using only the Spring AOP functionality? Here I could use Around advice as well but I guess that is a different issue. I checked various possibilities including EnclosingStaticPart and changing the pointcut definition with no success.

A quick solution was using StackTraceElement but I believe is not a good one.

Comment: Finally How you implemented ??

Answer (score 1):

A solution is provided [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/53443-any-way-for-the-advice-to-know-the-calling-object), requiring full  aspectj and not just spring-aop.

```
@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

    @Around("call(void com.spring.ioc.Aggregated.*(..))")
    public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxx: TestAspect.advice(): aspect is called on " + joinPoint
            + ". This object: " + joinPoint.getThis());
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```